# PythonTex stderr

Tags: pythontex

I am new to pythontex.
I could run simple python code.
However, I get error with slightly complex things.

The error I get is following:

```
This is PythonTeX 0.16

----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 211:
    File "<outputdir>\py_default_default.py", line 62
      MW= 18e-3 u.kilogram/ u.mole
                ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  notes - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:803: command failed with exit code 1:
python.exe c:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py notes.tex
```

Part of the code that has error is :

```
\begin{pycode}
import math
from pint import UnitRegistry
u = UnitRegistry()
alpha = 0.04
sigmaW = 72.86e-3 * u.newton / u.meter
mu    = 8.9e-4 * u.pascal * u.second
densityW = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
densityIPA = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
densityEtoh = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
H = 1e-6 * u.meter
W = 28e-6 * u.meter
L= 32e-6 * u.meter
MW= 18e-3 u.kilogram/ u.mole
MIPA= 60.1e-3 u.kilogram/ u.mole
MEtoh= 46.07e-3 u.kilogram/ u.mole
R0=8.31446 u.joule / (u.mole * u.kelvin)
T0= 298 u.kelvin
N= 10
D0=2.4e-5 (u.meter ** 2)/(u.second)
C0=17.08e-3 u.kilogram/(u.meter ** 3)
tauevW=(densityW * N * R0 * T0 * (W **3))/(6* math.pi * D0 * C0 * sigmaW * MW)
\end{pycode}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm no Python or `pint` expert, but while you had a `*` between number and unit in the first lines, you do not have that `*` in the last couple of lines. (Compare `L= 32e-6 * u.meter` and `MW= 18e-3 u.kilogram/ u.mole`) If I add a `*` everywhere I don't get an error with plain Python on the code.

Comment: Could you please paste it ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the lack of a multiplication sign between the number and units on line 62. Note that this omission is repeated on subsequent lines. The following has the operator added and executes without issue.

```
\begin{pycode}
import math
from pint import UnitRegistry
u = UnitRegistry()
alpha = 0.04
sigmaW = 72.86e-3 * u.newton / u.meter
mu    = 8.9e-4 * u.pascal * u.second
densityW = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
densityIPA = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
densityEtoh = 1000 * u.kilogram / (u.meter ** 3)
H = 1e-6 * u.meter
W = 28e-6 * u.meter
L = 32e-6 * u.meter
MW = 18e-3 * u.kilogram/ u.mole
MIPA = 60.1e-3 * u.kilogram/ u.mole
MEtoh = 46.07e-3 * u.kilogram/ u.mole
R0 = 8.31446 * u.joule / (u.mole * u.kelvin)
T0 = 298 * u.kelvin
N = 10
D0 = 2.4e-5 * (u.meter ** 2)/(u.second)
C0 = 17.08e-3 * u.kilogram/(u.meter ** 3)
tauevW = (densityW * N * R0 * T0 * (W **3))/(6* math.pi * D0 * C0 * sigmaW * MW)
\end{pycode}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted above. Now I get following error: ----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 364:
    File "<outputdir>\py_default_default.py", line 140
      import math
      ^
  IndentationError: unexpected indent

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  notes - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:803: command failed with exit code 1:
python.exe c:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py notes.tex

Comment: @T.D. The new error you get seems to be about a different line (about 80 lines further down) not shown in the initial post. The issues seems to be a Python problem and not a LaTeX error. So maybe you should ask at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The error is at "import math" ?

Comment: If I run following code. It runs properly. \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
    \LaTeX

\begin{pycode} 
print ('Hello, \LaTeX')
\end{pycode}
%\newline
\py{2+3}
%\newline



\end{document}

Comment: @T.D. Well, the error says “Unexpected indent”, so make sure you aren’t indenting the import math (and also everything after) line, since indentation has meaning in python.

Comment: I am a bit dissapointed. There is no easy way to setup python in windows. I just reinstalled python and now even simple script is not working. Latex gives no error. Is there a way to know python is properly installed via Latex or CMD windows.