# PythonTex stderr - error on line 364

Tags: pythontex

[image]  I am new to pythonTex. I get following error.
I checked working of simple python code.
However, when I try to import math within pycode it gives error.

### using code:

```
\begin{pycode}
import math 
from pint import UnitRegistry 
u = UnitRegistry() 
alpha = 0.04 
sigmaW = 72.86e-3 * u.newton / u.meter 
mu = 8.9e-4 * u.pascal * u.second 
\end{pycode}
```

---

I get following error:

```
----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 364:
    File "<outputdir>\py_default_default.py", line 140
      import math
      ^
  IndentationError: unexpected indent

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  notes - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:803: command failed with exit code 1:
python.exe c:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py notes.tex
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE) reproducing the error.

Comment: \begin{pycode}
import math
from pint import UnitRegistry
u = UnitRegistry()
alpha = 0.04
sigmaW = 72.86e-3 * u.newton / u.meter
mu    = 8.9e-4 * u.pascal * u.second   \end{pycode}

Comment: Please edit your post and insert the code there, because line breaks aren't preserved in comments.

Comment: The above code has "import math" at this point we get error.

Comment: @T.D. I already said in your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450377/pythontex-stderr#comment1132102_450379) that the error is an indentation error, have you made sure there's no (unnecessary) indentation within the pycode environment? Look at the `import math` line, there should not be any spaces/tabs before the `import` word.

Comment: I know, but your error message is about "unexpected indent" which means that linebreaks and indentation are important. I get another error (about the import, but as I do not have the module installed I could not test whether `from pint import math` works instead of `import from`).

Comment: How to check line break or indentation ?  I donot leave any space?  I also checked if pint is installed. It is there.

Comment: @T.D. Show us an image of your code in your text editor (where you edit your `.tex` file).

Comment: delete any auxiliary files generated by latex and pythontex (`.pytxcode` etc.), and make sure you run `pdflatex -> pythontex -> pdflatex` in that order.

Comment: I attached screen shot of code.

Comment: I cannot use pdflatex. I am using XeLatex instead.

Comment: run `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` then.. the point is to rerun the tex engine to regenerate the `pytxcode` file..

Comment: Is there a way to control indentation in TexStudio?  I updated the screenshot of configuration of TexStudio.

Comment: @Troy,  I get two set of pytxcode file. One in the folder "pythontex-files-python.." and one in working directory.

Comment: @T.D. Okay..? Just delete them (or copy them out if you want to backup just in case), rerun xelatex, then pythontex --> do you still get the unexpected indent error?

Comment: @Troy.  It works now. I just donot know how to get ride of all indentations. I removed them by hand. And the two set of pytxcode was due to two different versions of pythontex (one generated with cmd : pythontex file  and another generated due to TexStudio Config).  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @T.D. Hmm, highlight the lines you want to un-indent, then Shift+Tab several times until they all lie flush left.